# More efficient solution to clocks offset

Tags: python, math

I am writing a program where the user inputs two values: the number of minutes fast per hour that two clocks are. The output should be the time displayed on the clocks when the two clocks are showing the same time. The clocks are only checked once an hour (according to an accurate clock).

At the moment, I have:

```
clock1 = 0
clock2 = 0
inp = input(">").split(" ")
offset1 = int(inp[0])+60
offset2 = int(inp[1])+60

def add():
    global clock1
    global clock2
    clock1 += offset1
    if clock1 > 1399:
        clock1 -= 1440
    clock2 += offset2
    if clock2 > 1399:
        clock2 -= 1440

add()
while clock1 != clock2:
    add()

hours = 0
while clock1 > 59:
    hours += 1
    clock1 -= 60
while hours > 23:
    hours -= 24

hours = str(hours)
minutes = str(clock1)

if len(hours) == 1:
    hours = "0" + hours
if len(minutes) == 1:
    minutes = "0" + minutes

print(hours + ":" + minutes)
```

This works, but when the input values get big, it takes too long. How can I make this solution more efficient?

Comment: For starters, are you re-implementing integer division using while-loops? That is certainly wasteful. Also, what exactly is your `add` function doing? Why do you subtract 1440 when the value is over 1399... I don't understand the task - you should give an example input with expected output.

Comment: I would say, first find a nice mathematical solution and then write the code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for general review of fully functional code rather than asking a specific programming question. This sort of question is off topic here but may be on topic for [codereview.SE]. If it is, it can be migrated over there for you, so no need to repost it there.